# Can Python read value of cell in spreadsheet?

Tags: python, spreadsheet

Can Python read the value of a cell in a spreadsheet?

The simplest example would be a script that ran a buffer tool on a given shapefile.

For the distance parameter, instead of just using a number like '1000', the script would point to a value in a cell of a spreadsheet (libre or open office preferred).

*If* there was then a way to trigger the script from the spreadsheet by way of a button, that would be the next step (then the *next* step would be to have a map control inside the spreadsheet to see the updated results!)

Just to give some insight into where I'm going with this: I'd like to use a spreadsheet as an analysis 'dashboard' where users could run analysis with different parameters - what would proximity around parks (grocery stores, etc.) be at 1/2 mi vs 1/4 mi...then another sheet in the spreadsheet would have a breakdown of the demographics within that proximity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, use the [xlrd library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd).  See [parsing excel documents with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372716/parsing-excel-documents-with-python) question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

On windows and with MS office, you can use the [pywin32com](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) module to access the com-api (=same as VBA). This way you can also write to excel.
For example:

```
from win32com import client
excel=client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible=True
book=excel.Workbooks.Open("c:/desktop/test.xlsx", False, True)
sheet=book.Worksheets(1)
sheet.cells(1,1).value = "some text or number"
```